# how to return value of array from inside this closue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm spinning my wheels over here. How do I return the new value of onlinearray?

I want it so when I call the functions like so...

online()

I get the result onlinearray handed back to me.

```
  function online(){
    var offlinearray = [];
    var onlinearray  = [];
    console.log('called online');

    //foreach item in channels
    codeLib.channels().forEach(function(item){
      console.log(item);
      // run gotJSON
      codeLib.gotjson(item).done(function(result){
        if (result.stream == null) {
          // push into offline array
          offlinearray.push(item);
          console.log('OFFLINE array: '+ offlinearray );
        }else{
          // push into online array
          onlinearray.push(item);
          console.log('ONLINE array: ' + onlinearray); <--I can see values in console.log here
        }
      });

    });
    //console.log('inside: '+onlinearray);
    return onlinearray; <---doing something wrong here.
  }
```

gotjson is as follows...

```
  Codelib.prototype.gotjson = function(channel) {
     return $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+channel)
  };
```

Comment: I don't see any _closure_ here, it's normal function

Comment: Why do you assume the problem is at that line?

Comment: You can't do that with asynchronous calls.

Comment: `return onlinearray;` will return the array.  when you call the function, you need to assign the return value, like so:  `var result = online();`

Comment: could you clarify what does codeLib.channels() do? is it an async call? and gotjson?

Comment: I am guessing, like @crush and @rvalerio that the problem is an async call. `.gotjson` looks like a promise-returning function,  My advice would be refactor using promises.

Comment: BTW - if the collective assumption that these are async functions, the only way you will be able to have something close to your preferred calling syntax (i.e. `var result = online();` would be if you convert the online function to a generator using ES6 (or a ES6 to ES5 transpiler like Babel).

Comment: I have read the above link...Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code ....and I am still no closer to an answer. :(